# Wrong scope in javascript function when using 'self'

Tags: javascript

It appears that javascript scope is incorrect.  It doesn't look like a normal scope issue, in that using .call() or .bind() still results in the wrong scope.  The specific code uses Knockout and LoDash, but I don't think either library relates to this bug.  The core code elements are below:

```js
var FacilityDisplayModel = function (facility, options) {
   var self = facility ? facility : this;  
   self.Areas = ko.observableArray();
   ...
   self.hydrate = function (facilityHierarchy)
   {
      ...
      var areas = facilityHierarchy.Areas()
      for (var i in areas)
      {
       new AreaDisplayModel(areas[i], self, options);
      }
      self.Areas(areas);
      ...
   }

   self.hydrateHasCars = function(trackListWithoutCars){
     var hasCars = false;
     _.forEach(self.Areas(), function (area) {
        if(area.hydrateHasCars(trackListWithoutCars)) hasCars = true;
     });
     ...
   }
   return self;
}

var AreaBaseModel = function (area, parent, options) {
   var self = area ? area : this;
   if (self.Areas) {
      for (var i in self.Areas()) {
          new AreaDisplayModel(self.Areas()[i], self, options);
      }
   }
   ...
   return self;
}

var AreaDisplayModel = function (area, parent, options) {
    self = new AreaBaseModel(area, parent, options);
    self.Name;

    self.hydrateHasCars = function(trackListWithoutCars) {
        var hasCars = false;
        _.forEach(self.Areas(), function(area) {
            if (area.hydrateHasCars(trackListWithoutCars)) hasCars = true;
        });
    }
    ...
    return self;
}
```

This issue is that calling .hydrateHasCars() either with .call() or as a normal function results in the wrong scope for the result.  It ends up using the current instance scope instead of the child scope.

For example, we are in an area with Name "Area 1".  As we foreach through the Areas, the first area is called "Area 1.1".  This is a seperate instance of the same object.  But calling .hydrateHasCars() on "Area 1.1" results in a self of "Area 1".  Even when using .call(area, ...), specifically setting the scope to "Area 1.1" it still results in a 'self' scope of "Area 1".

Edit:  I've updated the code snippet to include more code.  I've included as much as I think could possibly be relevant to this issue.  The code flow is like this:  a facility is hydrated with information from the server, building out Areas, with sub-Areas underneath them.  We then get car information from the server and go through the areas, updating them.  We need to know whether a sub-Area has cars in order to know if it's parent area has cars.  Here lies the scope issue, where the parent area calls the child area, but the while debugging, I can see that the 'self' in the call is referring to the parent and not the child.

The workaround I've found is treating hydrateHasCars as 'static' and passing in the area as below:

```js
self.hydrateHasCars = function(parentArea, trackListWithoutCars) {
    var hasCars = false;
    _.forEach(parentArea.Areas(), function(area) {
        if (area.hydrateHasCars(area, trackListWithoutCars)) hasCars = true;
    });
};
```

However, I'd rather use non-'static' methods and fix the scope issue.

Comment: You could bind `self` to your function, and access it with `this`.  Check [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: How are you calling `AreaDisplayModel`? What is `this` supposed to be when you call it?

Comment: Creating a closure `var self = this;`and using it right away `self.hydrateHasCars = `makes no sense.. Its the same as `this.hydrateHasCars =`

Comment: @Barmar I'm calling `var area = new AreaDisplayModel()`.  `this` is supposed to be the child scope of the area called "Area 1.1", but is incorrectly resulting in the scope of the caller, "Area 1".  @James, `self` is a way to avoid needing to use function.bind().  However, I did try using `.bind(this)` just in case, and it resulted in the same error.

Comment: Could you provide enough code that we can actually see the problem? It's really hard to tell what's happening based on the snippets you've posted.